# android facebook share dialog work just once. Other times show something went wrong

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I am editing older app using facebook-android-sdk-3.17.2, which show shareDialog to user. When I try to share something for the first time, everything run okej, my app pair with personal facebook account and then share content I wish.

But when I try to share content again, facebook app show me "Sorry, something went wrong. We're worknikg on it and we'll get it fixed as soon as we can"

I try check App ID, check Facebook Hash, clean chache and cookies in browser too. Strage is that for the first time all works fine. All other times it show error above.

I try to remove my app from my personal facebook account, and it works again, but only once(again).

Comment: Might Facebook has down